# xctest using NSPredicate to replace eventually of Quick/Nimble

Tags: swift, nspredicate, xctest

I am trying to convert below test case from quick/nimble to xctest:

```
expect(foundation.appGuid).toEventually(equal(guidValue))
```

Below is the code i am using but the test crashes:

```
let successPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", guidValue)
    expectation(for: successPredicate, evaluatedWith: foundation.appGuid) {
      return foundation.appGuid == guidValue
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) -> Void in
      if error != nil {
        XCTFail("foundation.appGuid NOT Equal to guidValue")
      }
    }
```

Am i doing something wrong in above code ?

Comment: Is guidValue the same type as appGuid?

Comment: yes they are same type

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
let successPredicate = NSPredicate(format:  "SELF == %@", self.guidValue)
    expectation(for: successPredicate, evaluatedWith: foundation.serviceConfig.appGuid) {
      return foundation.serviceConfig.appGuid == self.guidValue
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) -> Void in
      if error != nil {
        XCTFail("foundation.serviceConfig.appGuid NOT Equal to guidValue")
      }
    }
```

Comment: used == instead of MATCHES since MATCHES if for regular expressions